# How can UIActivityIndicatorView do not stop when the mainThread blocked?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsthread, uiactivityindicatorview

How can `UIActivityIndicatorView`  do not stop when the *mainThread* blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can as the view uses the main thread itself to perform the animation. If you are performing long-running processes on the main thread (e.g. network, or long computational processes) consider changing your design. E.g. use GCD, threads etc.